# Colouring the text on the video

Tags: css

I am using the Listify theme and I want to change the colour of the text on homepage video. Below is my code in which I have video and text

```
[video width="1280" height="720" mp4="http://abcd.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/abcd.mp4" loop="true" autoplay="true" preload="auto" webm="http://abcd.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/abcd.webm"][/video]

<span style="color: #ffffff;">Thinking Good, Living Good!</span>
```

Problem is that the text that is apearing above the video is the HTML code - "Thinking Good, Living Good!" rather than the text "Thinking Good, Living Good!" in White Colour.

Answer (score 0):

HTML entered into the Visual editor will not be rendered as HTML. Use the Text editor for HTML.